# Одинаковый hashCode() у объектов, но они не эквивалентны

Tags: java, hashcode

Добрый вечер!
Почему два объекта имеют одинаковый хэш код, но при этом могут быть не эквивалентны в смысле эквивалентности по функции **equals()**.Есть ли пример?
PS коллизии не трогать

Comment: Определите hashCode таким образом, чтобы он возвращал константу, вот и весь пример.

Comment: зачем? я определю ее как функцию, считающую хэш код по какому нибудь алгоритму от каждой функции и поля в классе.
Я имею ввиду, что у меня есть адекватная функция , которая возращает хэш код. Он абсолютно верен для объекта. И он уникален(коллизии не считаются). Почему в этом случае нельзя его использовать для сравнения, в функции equals()

Comment: @voipp ТОгда ваш PS про коллизии не в тему, ибо ровно из за них и получается одинаковый хэшкод для разных объектов. ОДЗ для всех полей вашего класса шире, чем ОДЗ для hashCode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите. Сколько возможных значений `hashCode`? Разумеется, `2^32`, так как `hashCode` имеет тип `int`.

А сколько у нас возможно различных объектов типа `String`? Явно больше, чем `2^32`, потому что у нас как минимум `2^32` различных строк, соответствующих представлению целых чисел, и плюс ещё множество других строк. Поэтому обязательно разные строки будут иметь одинаковые хэшкоды: строк много, а хэшкодов мало. Очевидно, что разные строки не имеют права равняться друг другу по `equals`.

Не совсем понимаю ваш PS: коллизия — это именно тот случай, когда объекты разные, а хэшкоды совпадают. Как же не трогать этот случай, когда он именно вас и интересует?

Comment: О , спасибо. Теперь понятно. Меня на одном форуме запутали:
I - You mean because of collisions , objects with equal hash code could not be compared by equals() function ?
Forum citizen - No. Collisions are irrelevant in this case. The rules are that two objects which have the same hashCode may or may not be equal as determined by the 
equals() method. But if the objects are equal as determine by the equals() method, then the hashCodes must be the same. Otherwise, the objects won't play well with maps.

Comment: @voipp: Ну, тот комментатор прав в том, что если `a.equals(b)`, то `a.hashCode()` и `b.hashCode()` обязаны быть равны. Но вы были правы — давайте я только сформулирую по-другому:

> Объекты, у которых хэшкоды равны, могут быть и неравны по `equals`. Такая ситуация _называется_ хэш-коллизией.

Answer (score 1):

Короткий ответ: такая спецификация

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29

- Whenever it is invoked on the same
     object more than once during an
     execution of a Java application, the
     hashCode method must consistently
     return the same integer, provided no
     information used in equals
     comparisons on the object is
     modified. This integer need not
     remain consistent from one execution
     of an application to another
     execution of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to
     the equals(Object) method, then
     calling the hashCode method on each
     of the two objects must produce the
     same integer result.
- It is not required that if two
     objects are unequal according to the
     equals(java.lang.Object) method, then
     calling the hashCode method on each
     of the two objects must produce
     distinct integer results. However,
     the programmer should be aware that
     producing distinct integer results
     for unequal objects may improve the
     performance of hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

По общепринятому соглашению хеш код не обязательно, должен однозначно определять объект (хотя такое тоже допускается), при большом количестве объектов вполне нормально, чтобы для разных объектов гипотетически генерировался одинаковый хеш код. Хеш код должен быть достаточно хорошо распределенным, вероятность одинакового хеш кода для разных объектов должна быть минимальной, для хеш кода как правило (если это конечно не шифрование :)) желательно максимально высокая скорость вычисления (критично для алгоритмов сортировок, балансировки деревьев с ключом в виде хешкода), для equals()при проверки только на равенство хешкодов может быть критичной (по бизнес логике) ситуация с одинаковых хешкодом для разных объектов, поэтому в нем определяют более сложную логику проверки и как следствие более медленную.

хеш код String в Java образцово показательный, с точки зрения красоты реализации, а вот equals()для String еще стоит подумать как определить, сравнивать ли посимвольным образом, выкидывать ли пробелы, учитывать ли регистр :)

Comment: но вот имея большое количество объектов в хэш-таблице мы получаем преимущество в скорости, но при этом растет вероятность коллизии.вот в чем беда, но мне кажется будет не обреминительным после нахождения кандидата в хэш-таблице, делать проверку по **equals**. А так же необходимо следить, что бы объекты хэш-ключей не изменялись.